# How to add full username to a list returned by get-acl?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl

I want to prepare a list of persons having access to a given folder. The list should also contain the level of access granted. I figured out the following powershell command:

```
Get-Acl \\path\to\my\folder | Select-Object path -ExpandProperty Access | ft IdentityReference, FileSystemRights
```

This is almost what I need. I want to replace *IdentityReference* column with a column containing full user names. I am trying to achieve it by passing *IdentityReference* value to `Get-QADUser` cmdlet, but I do not know how to format the output to see both the full user name and *FileSystemRights* column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, but **untested**

```
Get-Acl  | 
   Select-Object path -ExpandProperty Access | 
      select IdentityReference, FileSystemRights | 
         Select @{n='identity';e={$_.IdentityReference}},* | Get-QADUser
```

Comment: Thank you. I managed to run your code with minor modifications: I had to add `.Value` after `$_.IdentityReference`. But it still does not give the output I want. How to combine `FileSystemRights` returned by Get-Acl with `Name` property returned by `Get-QADUser` into a single table?

Comment: After some experiments I managed to achieve the desired result:
`Get-Acl \\my\folder | Select-Object path -ExpandProperty Access | select @{n='User';e={ (Get-QADUser -Identity $_.IdentityReference.Value).Name }},FileSystemRights`. I am accepting your answer as it pushed me in right direction :-)

Comment: For those who do not want to install Active Directory Module form quest I modified the solution to work with built-in AD cmdlets:
`Get-Acl \\my\folder | Select-Object Path -ExpandProperty Access | Select-Object @{n='User';e={ (Get-ADUser -Identity $_.IdentityReference.Value.Split("\")[1]).Name }},FileSystemRights`